# Cannot configure matplotlib rcparams for plot color

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am not able to change default color from blue to red using **plt.rc()** or **mpl.rcparams**
According to Matplotlib's [official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#dynamic-rc-settings)
[image: This should be the output]

Here is the code I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.random.randn(50)
mpl.rcParams['lines.color'] = 'r'
plt.plot(data)
```

Output:
[image: Not able to change default color from blue to red]

Comment: The documentation is wrong at that point. Further down in the rc template you find `#lines.color       : C0      ## has no affect on plot(); see axes.prop_cycle`. And the image is only red, because the default first color of the ggplot style is red. You can create an issue about it at the issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest , I have created an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a relatively new `matplotlib` version (i.e. 1.5+) you should use `axes.prop_cycle`as described [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/color_cycle_demo.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.random.randn(50)

import cycler
plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = cycler.cycler(color='r')

plt.plot(data)
```

[image]